# --ignore-ssl-errors=true option not working for casperjs test in x86_64 GNU/Linux

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

`--ignore-ssl-errors=true` option not working for casperjs test in  x86_64 GNU/Linux

The same test id working in Windows.

I am using the phantom js 1.9.7

Can any one please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use specific ssl version = TLSv1

```
casperjs --ssl-protocol=TLSv1 --ignore-ssl-errors=true my.js
```